# SQL Get Ranges after grouping records

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have an SQL table having an input table with below records

```
srno|dispatch|PrintedPagesfromNo|PrintedPagestoNo|done
----+--------+------------------+----------------+----
1   |Post    |1                 |5               |N         
2   |Post    |6                 |10              |N         
3   |Post    |11                |13              |N         
4   |Courier |14                |16              |N         
5   |Post    |17                |20              |N         
6   |Courier |21                |25              |N         
7   |Courier |26                |30              |N         
8   |Post    |31                |40              |N         
9   |Courier |41                |50              |N
```

I want to write a SQL query to generate the output like the below

```
Dispatch|PrintedPagesfromNo|PrintedPagestoNo
--------+------------------+----------------
Post    |1                 |13
Post    |17                |20
Post    |31                |40
Courier |14                |16
Courier |21                |30
Courier |41                |50
```

The requirement is to show the user limited ranges after grouping sequential entries.

I will show the same to user on ASP.net website using C# after generating the above table.

Also, The above table will have multiple inserts during run-time.

Comment: To be clear: is the grouping here based on order by `srno`, for matching `dispatch` values? i.e. a new group whenever `dispatch` changes, then order by `Dispatch` then `PrintedPagesfromNo` ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to solve an "islands and gaps" problem - where you're wanting to merge rows where the ranges are contiguous, is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: with the clarification in comments, I suspect you need to use a recursive CTE to do this:

```sql
with my_cte ([Root], dispatch, PrintedPagesfromNo, PrintedPagestoNo)
as (
  select h.srno, h.dispatch, h.PrintedPagesfromNo, h.PrintedPagestoNo
  from #foo h
  where not exists(
      select 1 from #foo l
      where h.dispatch = l.dispatch and h.PrintedPagesfromNo = l.PrintedPagestoNo + 1)
  union all
  select l.[Root], l.dispatch, h.PrintedPagesfromNo, h.PrintedPagestoNo
  from my_cte l
  inner join #foo h on h.dispatch = l.dispatch
                    and h.PrintedPagesfromNo = l.PrintedPagestoNo + 1
)
select dispatch, MIN(PrintedPagesfromNo) as PrintedPagesfromNo,
                 MAX(PrintedPagestoNo) as PrintedPagestoNo
from my_cte
group by [Root], dispatch
ORDER  BY dispatch DESC, MIN(PrintedPagesfromNo)
```

(replace `#foo` with your table name)

Note that `h` denotes "higher", `l` denotes "lower"; this works by first finding the blocks that don't have a previous lower blocks  of the same `dispatch` and adjacent range, then recurses finding *adjacent* blocks each time for the same `dispatch`, then groups by the roots to find the overall ranges.

---

Well that was fun:

```sql
WITH batches AS (
    SELECT *, srno - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dispatch ORDER BY srno) AS batch
    FROM   [YourTableName])

SELECT dispatch,
       MIN(PrintedPagesfromNo) AS PrintedPagesfromNo,
       MAX(PrintedPagestoNo) AS PrintedPagestoNo
FROM   batches
GROUP  BY dispatch, batch
ORDER  BY dispatch DESC, MIN(PrintedPagesfromNo)
```

Note that this assumes that `srno` are reliably contiguous. Without that, you'd need an additional `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY srno)`:

```sql
WITH batches AS (
    SELECT x.dispatch, x.PrintedPagesfromNo, x.PrintedPagestoNo,
       _row - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dispatch ORDER BY _row) AS batch
    FROM   (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY srno) as _row
            FROM [YourTableName]) x)

SELECT dispatch,
       MIN(PrintedPagesfromNo) AS PrintedPagesfromNo,
       MAX(PrintedPagestoNo) AS PrintedPagestoNo
FROM   batches
GROUP  BY dispatch, batch
ORDER  BY dispatch DESC, MIN(PrintedPagesfromNo)
```

Comment: This will not work in the case there are gaps in the records<br/> 1 Post 1 5 N<br/>         
2 Post 6 8 N <br/>        
3 Post 11 13 N<br/> This will return the output as <br/>Post 1 13

Comment: @Danish_k12 which version, and what type of gaps? The second version should work, because I am intentionally collapsing the gaps via the generation of `_row` as `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY srno)`. I *should* however, probably tweak the primary partitioned ORDER BY clause to use `_row` rather than `srno` - however, that mainly addresses the issue of *duplicates*, not *gaps*

Comment: @Danish_k12 see, that is why I asked for clarification of the specification ;p see edit

Comment: This Worked! Can you tell me which technique you used. I can also learn the same.

Comment: @Danish_k12 simply recursion to identify successive ranges; the code is all there... (I even already added a paragraph explaining what it was doing)